# Could not execute statement.Can't open a connection to site 'SYB_BACKUP'. See the error log file in the ASE boot directory

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Could not execute statement.
Can't open a connection to site 'SYB_BACKUP'. See the error log file in
the ASE boot directory.
Sybase error code=7205
Severity Level=17, State=2, Transaction State=1
Line 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRr8M.png)

Answer (score 2):

The (SAP/Sybase) backupserver is a separate OS process running on the same host as the ASE/dataserver process, so there are a few things you can check:

- Have you been able to successfully run `dump` and/or `load` commands previously against this dataserver, or is this the first time you've attempted a `load` command? [If the former then this is likely an issue of the backupserver process not running; if the latter then this may be an issue with an incomplete/incorrect installation of the product.]
- Is the backupserver process running on the host where the ASE process is running? [For Windows environments this is usually configured as a service.]
- Has the dataserver's SYB_BACKUP (logical) server been configured to reference the correct backusperver name? [Run `sp_helpserver SYB_BACKUP` and make note of the name under `network_name`; is this the name of the backupserver?]
- Make sure the backupserver is defined in the dataserver's interfaces/sql.ini file. [Is the backupserver - displayed under `sp_helpserver/network_name` - listed in the `sql.ini` file?]

Answer (score 0):

Huh.  Being new I can't add a comment, so I'm putting it here.  What command are you executing?